# Song database query

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I am relatively inexperienced with MySQL and have a query, which to my eyes appears relatively complex:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    songsID, song_name, artist_band_name, author, song_artwork, song_file,
    genre, song_description, uploaded_time, emotion, tempo,
    user, happiness, instruments, similar_artists, play_count,
    projects_count,
    rating, ratings_count, waveform, datasize, display_name, user_url, genre_id,
    IF(user_ratings_count, 'User Voted', 'Not Voted') as voted 
FROM (
        SELECT  
            sp.songsID, projects_count, 
            AVG(rating) as rating,
            COUNT(rating) AS ratings_count,
            COUNT(IF(userid=$userid, 1, NULL)) as user_ratings_count

                FROM (
                    SELECT songsID, COUNT(*) as projects_count
                    FROM $sTable s
                    LEFT JOIN $sTable2 p ON s.songsID = p.songs_id

                    GROUP BY songsID) as sp

            LEFT JOIN $sTable3 r ON sp.songsID = r.songid


            GROUP BY sp.songsID) as spr


JOIN $sTable s USING (songsID)
LEFT JOIN $sTable5 q ON s.user = q.ID   
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT g.song_id, GROUP_CONCAT(g.genre_id SEPARATOR ',') as genre_id
            FROM $sTable6 g   
            JOIN $sTable h ON h.songsID = g.song_id       
            GROUP by h.songsID) as gs 
            ON s.songsID = gs.song_id
```

Essentially, this query collects data from several different tables about a list of songs:

- The song table itself is `$sTable` with the other tables containing various related information such as ratings, projects, uploaded user information etc.
- The final part of the query collects a comma-separated list of `genre_id`s from `$sTable6`.
- The `WHERE` clause is dynamically generated depending on what the user is filtering upon.

I am specifically concerned about the fact that I am currently dynamically generating the `WHERE` clause when a user wants to search by `genre_id`, by looping through a string of comma-separated `genre_id`s and building the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
WHERE genre_id LIKE '%6%' OR genre_id LIKE '%3%' OR genre_id LIKE '%8%'
```

This strikes me as inefficient but given the dynamic nature of this specific app I have been unable to come up with a different solution that compares directly using '`=`'.

Therefore, this is actually two questions in one:

1. Is there any way to improve the performance of this query overall (any comments on on index schemes or a way of simplifying the query itself are most welcome)?
2. Is there a better way of performing the dynamic `WHERE` clause so the database doesn't have to use `LIKE` searching through comma separated strings?

The table in question, `$sTable6`, is simply a link table for a many-to-many relationship:

> ```
> $stable (songs)        $stable6 (genres_link)    $sTable7 (genres)
> songsID*               genre_id**                genre_id**
> column                 song_id*                  genre_name
> column                                           icon_url  etc....
> column
> column
> ```

`$sTable 7` is not used in the above query at all and does not need to be.

I get the following returned via MySQL `EXPLAIN` when using a simple 2 genre_id `WHERE` clause (with only 9 rows of songs in total, I will be testing large datasets soon).

> ```
> id    select_type table       type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref                     rows    Extra
> 1     PRIMARY     <derived4>  ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL    NULL                    2   Using where
> 1     PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL    NULL                    9   Using where; Using join buffer
> 1     PRIMARY     s           eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4       gs.song_id              1   
> 1     PRIMARY     q           eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     8       songbanc_cms.s.user     1   
> 4     DERIVED     g           index   PRIMARY         PRIMARY     8       NULL                    6   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
> 4     DERIVED     h           eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4       songbanc_cms.g.song_id  1   Using index
> 2     DERIVED     <derived3>  ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL    NULL                    9   Using temporary; Using filesort
> 2     DERIVED     r           ref     PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4       sp.songsID              2   Using index
> 3     DERIVED     s           index   NULL            PRIMARY     4       NULL                    2   Using index
> 3     DERIVED     p           ref     songs_id        songs_id    4       songbanc_cms.s.songsID  4   Using index
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know is it help or not (since it's a really complicated query) but it's usually worth caching computed values such as `rating` and `ratings_count` and updating them once a day or an hour for example. In the majority of the cases it's enough to provide non-real-time data to the users.

Comment: Good point palacsint, thanks, that will definitely help.

Comment: In addition to @palacsint, I usually fire a DDBB trigger to do this kind of taks, as adding number of votes, add/substract pictures in a gallery, etc.